# file python menu going back to menu after first option

Tags: python, file, menu

```
def menu():
print('Choose number to continue: ')
print('1 to create file')
print('2 to read file')
print('3 to append to file')
print('4 to calculate')
print('5 to quit')

def choice():
    choice=int(input('Enter menu choice: '))
    return choice


def option1():
    filename=input('Enter file name: ')
    file=open(filename,'w')
    print('Enter integers to be written to file and press enter when done.')
    count=1
    fox=1
    while count>=1:
        filedata=str(input('Enter integer '+str(fox)+' : '))
        count+=1
        fox+=1
        file.write(filedata)
        if filedata=='':
            file.close()
            menu
            break

def option2():
    try:
        open(file,'r')
        for line in file.readlines():
            print(line)
            file.close()
            menu()
    except:
        print('Error. You must first create a file in order to read it.')


def option3():
    try:
        open(file,'a')
        print('Enter integers to be appended to file and press enter when done.')
        count=1
        while count>=1:
         appenddata=int(input('Enter integer to append: '))
        count+=1
        file.write(appenddata)
        if appendata=='':
            file.close()
            menu

    except:
        print('Error. You must first create a file in order to read it.')



def option4():
    file= open('file', 'r')
    s = file.readlines()
    p = str(s)



    for line in s:
        printnum = 0

        total=0
        printnum += int(line)
        total += printnum


        print("The sum is: ", total)
        menu()


def option5():
    quit

def main():
    menu()
    t=choice()

    if t==1:
       option1()
       menu() 
    elif t==2:
        option2()
        menu
    elif t==3:
        option3()
        menu()
    elif t==4:
        option4()
        menu()
    else:
        option5()
main()
```

Sorry about the lengthy code, here is a menu driven python program I'm making.
It lets user select first option, then prints the menu and then ends when instead I'd like it to let them input menu choice again. I can see *why* it's doing that but I cant think of a way to allow them to pick second/third/fourth option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop to repeat your menu.

```
def main():

    menu()
    t=choice()
    while t != 5:    
        if t==1:
            option1()
        elif t==2:
            option2()
        elif t==3:
            option3()
        elif t==4:
            option4()
        else:
            print('Invalid Choice')

        print('')
        menu()
        t=choice()

# main
main()
```